# Datatables not working pre filter

Tags: javascript, datatables

The javascript datatables work when I select one of three radio buttons below. But, when I load the html with the second radio button checked firsthand, the datatables filter is not working. How can I filter when the html is loading? I have tried to put `grid.draw()` before `onclick` and also inside `onload`, but it is not working.

This is my HTML page

```
<div id="filter" class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-4"><input type="radio" name="type" id="test1" />Test 1</label>
    <label class="col-sm-4"><input type="radio" name="type" id="test2" checked />Test 2</label>
    <label class="col-sm-4"><input type="radio" name="type" id="test3" />Test 3</label>
</div>
```

This is the javascript

```
$(function () {
  var grid = $('#table').DataTable();
  $(document).on("click", '#filter', function(){
    grid.draw();
  });
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      // do something
    }
  );
});
```

`$('#table')` contains the html table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return what you want to filter in the push. Example with a specific date

```
return data.date < day
```

Then outside of push you need to redraw the table.